# How not to load extensions (e.g. ReSharper) when running VS in Debugging Mode?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-addins

When debugging Add-ins for Visual Studio 2013, a lot of time wasted for loading symbols for the extensions that are completely unrelated to what I’m doing (ReSharper blinks in front of my eyes all the time and makes me feel dizzy); loading of these extensions also produces a lot of noise in the Output pane.

Add-in Manager has option to load or not to load Add-ins depending on whether VS was called from the command line. Does such possibility exist for ReSharper and other extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing VS Extensions, when you hit F5, Visual Studio pops up in [the Experimental Hive.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx)

You may want to remove Resharper from your exp instance, as that will really speed up debugging (you won’t have to suffer the slow-down caused by the debugger loading symbols forResharper’s millions of assemblies..). 
To do this:

1. Go to \Common7\IDE\Extensions\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.1, you'll find two shortcuts
2. Move (don't copy) those shortcuts to %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions

ReSharper will now only load for the normal instance (the one you're writing your code in, not the one that pops up when you hit F5). You can add and remove it to any other instance simply by copying those two shortcuts to %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_\Extensions

The process is similar for other extensions as well, it's usually just about copying thing from `<visual studio install dir>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\` to `<visual studio install dir>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\`. YMMV.

Comment: When debugging Add-ins (not the other types of extension packages), VS uses more archaic technology (dated back to VS 2005 or even earlier version) that does not use Experimental VS: it simply invokes the copy of the ordinary VS with all installed extensions.